# Unable to store complete json field in mysql table field

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, database

I am getting a large json data in a api response. I am trying to store this json response in local mysql table. But unable to store complete json response. Please find the below json info.

## Sample API json response :

```
{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "date": "2020-06-03",
    "message": "Success",
    "couponDetails": {
        "total": 14949,
        "codes": "35033769,35441136,35803675,34407176,34717909,34950692,35059148,35452352,35688911,35904465,35904658,35904753,35904824,35904942,35905306,35905318,35905434,35905673,35906615,35907029,35907154,35907222,35907345,35907592,35907683,35907951,35908161,35908194,35908206,34664348,34664436,34665057,34665072,34665768,34665950,34666051,34666110,34666879,34667228,34668101,34670133,34670162,34670259,34670661,34670687,34670994,34671179,34671296,34672207,34672276,34672631,34672747,34673619,34673709,34675355,34676588,34677690,34678019,34679260,34679468,34680550,34680694,34680838,34683321,34684752,34684796,34685198,34685826,34686220,34686276,34351922,34352193,34352369,34352553,34353629,34353971,34355064,34355541,34355625,34356802,34357668,34357869,34357922,34360451,34360500,34360764,34361049,34361174,34361315,34362337,34362412,34363370,34364187,34365025,34365188,34365415,34365904,34366777,34366877,34367361,34368025,34368078,35542974,35543013,35543084,35268238,35268397,35268774,35269689,35269933,35270038,35250597,35063719,35064231,35064237,35270577,35270705,35270969,35064514,35064963,35065129,35251645,35251660,35251798,35253022,35253300,35272389,35272446,35272519,35272640,35272641,35273596,35273716,35423127,35423184,35423372,35424244,35425607,35485524,35486647,35486711,35486970,35487111,35470199,35470485,35488099,35488145,35488270,35490204,35534378,35535484,35535520,35535559,35535601,35535818,21979363,21508096,26237385,24734847,22263784,26889428,29292212,20415646,21836743,20300178,21831783,21198543,23739734,29773862,20715551,25488915,28894112,26536357,26695866,27133857,29133336,28763373,21850298,21990790,27757421,2421785723"
    }
}
```

In my local DB table I am able to insert the below information only, which is not complete :

```
{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "date": "2020-06-03",
    "message": "Success",
    "couponDetails": {
        "total": 14949,
        "codes": "35033769,35441136,35803675,34407176,34717909,34950692,35059148,35452352,35688911,35904465,35904658,35904753,35904824,35904942,35905306,
```

## Mysql Table Structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `bookdata_codeinfo_history` (
  `generated_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_code` longtext,
  `service` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to store json in '**book_code**' field but only few information is storing. I am using mysql-5.7.13 version.
Please tell me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Did you double-check whether the table structure of both local/production is same? `longtext`s limit is beyond your json.

Comment: Yes, I checked it, its same. In production it is perfectly storing.

Comment: What value is actually storing?  Can you supply the exact string?  Curious how many characters are stored

Comment: The json storing like the below format in the field
'{\"responseCode\":200,\"date\":\"2020-06-02\",\"message\":\"Success\",\"couponDetails\":{\"total\":14949,\"codes\":\"35904465,35904658,35904753,35904824,35904942,35905306,35905318,35905434,35905673,35906615,35907029,35907154,35907222,35907345,35907592,35907683,35907951,35908161,35908194,35908206,34664348,34664436,34665057,34665072,34665768,34665950,34666051,34666110,34666879,34667228,34668101,34670133,34670162,34670259,34670661,34670687,34670994,34671179,34671296,34672207,34672276,34672631,34672747,34673619,3467',

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than attempting to store the book codes as a string, a better way to model the table would be to break the book_code string into individual rows.

This would help in searching the data and future extensibility of the data model.

Answer (score 0):

That's really strange a LONGTEXT can support up to 4,294,967,295 bytes  ~4GB. (kindly recheck your table strucure) . 

 Or 
Put these jsons in files and save the path in the database

 Or 
 
Split the codes fields into multiple row, something like idrequest , code and every code contains one value